# How to connect to the Internet via 3g modem in the FreeBSD terminal?

Tags: terminal, freebsd

I installed FreeBSD, but it does not have a default GUI, so I have to install it myself.
I watched a lot of videos about installing the GUI in FreeBSD, and there all the video authors install it by connecting to the Internet via wifi-router, but to connect to the Internet I have only a 3g modem huawei.

The problem is that I can not connect to the Internet via a 3g modem on the FreeBSD terminal.
I was looking for a solution in google but I did not find a solution. Maybe someone knows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately unless you are happy using a terminal this is not easy. A 3g modem behaves in a manner very similar to ancient dialup modems, ie by using Hayes AT commands to "dial" a remote connection [ this does not use a phone number ], and then to set up a PPP connection on top of it.   There are tutorials on specifics [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/28482/) and [here](https://www.anywi.com/3g/wiki/PPPFor3GModems).   This is invariably set up at the command line.

That said, if you value your time, it would probably be a lot easier to simply get a basic android cellphone and use WIFI tethering.